# What are this Weird Character on my Ajax result

Tags: php, ajax, perl

What are this Weird Characters on my Ajax result 138d on the start and 0 on the end of my ajax result. how to disable this?

```
138d


{"feeds":[{"pubdate":"Sun, 28 Nov 2021 23:00:00 EST"]}
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP client is buggy. It improperly extracted the body from the HTTP response.

---

There are three ways to signaling the end of an HTTP response:

- Using a `Content-Length` header.
- Using the `chunked` transfer coding.
- Closing the socket.

The first two methods allow more than one request-response exchange to occur over the same connection, which is far more efficient than creating a new connection for each request. (Especially for HTTPS.)

The `Content-Length` header is quite simple to use, but it requires knowing the size of the message body before starting to send it.  The `chunked` transfer coding doesn't have that limitation. It allows servers to start sending a response before its size becomes known.

An HTTP response that uses the chunked transfer coding might look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK␍␊
Transfer-Encoding: chunked␍␊
Content-Type: application/json␍␊
␍␊
28␍␊
..............................␍␊
28␍␊
..............................␊␍␊
0␍␊
```

The message body of that response is

```
............................................................␊
```

The response that returned your JSON apparently used the `chunked` transfer coding. And whatever you used to parse the HTTP response incorrectly returned the still-chunked message body. This is a bug. Quote [RFC2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616),

> All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the
> "chunked" transfer-coding

Comment: Thanks a lot ikegami. I tried to disabled the gzip in my apache server then it is fixed. thanks for the help.